# Finding height of a triangle with vectors

Tags: vectors

I'm given a triangle with coordinates $A(3,6)$, $B(-1,3)$ and $C(2,-1)$. Find the length of height of that triangle.
Well I know how to find it with constructing some lines normal to sides of that triangle, finding intersection etc. and calculating lengths, but is there a trick to do it easier with vectors? Like using vector or scalar product for example?

Comment: Is there a particular height you want, for example, the height from side AB to C?

Comment: Oh my error. Problem says to find all heights.

Comment: You just need to calculate the distance of a point, lets say $C$ from the line through the remaining points (in this case AB). The easiest way is to determine twice the area with the cross product and divide by the length of the side corresponding to the height.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the vector $AB$ and the vector $AC$. Recall that $||AB \times AC||$ represents  the area of the parallelogram with the sides equal in lengths and direction to the vectors $AB$ and $AC$ (here ||<>|| denotes magnitude and $\times$ denotes the cross product). Take $AB$ to be the base then using the fact $(b)(h)=\text{area}$ we have:

$$h=\frac{\text{area}}{b}=\frac{||AB \times AC||}{||AB||}$$

The height in the parallelogram  is the same height as in the triangle with the same sides, if you take the base to be the same.

Note:

The cross product may not make that much sense in $2-D$ geometrically, so work in $3-D$. Just take the components of the vectors $AB$ and $AC$ along the $z$ axis to be $0$ and then work like usual.

Comment: You're welcome @DarkoDekan  I just want to add one more note. Please check it out.